# Social network scheme without server software

Tags: network-programming, peer

(I realize that this question might cost me a reputation score I still want to ask:)

Imagine a social networking software much like a trivial Facebook (Adding friends, sharing statuses and chatting) where the only software component needed is a client app. With no server farms and with no sensitive data stored on servers with no government control and with no server software at all.

Well while this is theoretically almost possible (If there is at least known one user address) still I cant figure out a way how can clients discover each other in the internet (Not in local IP range) if there is not some server where all client addresses are recorded in a least case.

Please drop any ideas how client can discover each other in the internet without server software if you got one or if there is already precedence case.

Comment: Can the clients manually (over a phone call) exchange info to connect with each other?

Comment: http://twister.net.co/ <-- Already exists.